# Cannot read property 'sourceEvent' of null in event listeners

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

I just started to learn d3.js library. I need to make a svg editor and I taught it is a good idea to use this one. I have a problem, I wrote some functions and I want those functions to run on a mouse click.

The functions create a line from point A to a point B, so I need to call those functions only when <kbd>Line</kbd> button is clicked.

Here is the block of code:

```
var line;
var container = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .on('mousedown',mousedown)
    .on('mouseup',mouseup);


function mousedown() {
    var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
        line = container.append("line")
        .attr("x1", coordinates[0])
        .attr("y1", coordinates[1])
        .attr("x2", coordinates[0])
        .attr("y2", coordinates[1]);

container.on("mousemove", mousemove);
};

 function mousemove(){
    var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
        line.attr("x2", coordinates[0])
            .attr("y2", coordinates[1]);
};
function mouseup(){
     container.on("mousemove", null);
};
```

html

```
<button id="lineBtn">Line</button>
```

css

```
line {
   stroke: black;
   stroke-width: 3px;
}

svg{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-right:40%; 
}
```

Comment: When/where do you see the error in your title?

Comment: When binding the functions on a button.    document.getElementById("lineBtn").onclick = function drawLine(){
    mousedown();
    mousemove();
    mouseup();
}

Comment: What do you mean by `start those functions only when Line button is clicked`?  That you first have to click the line button before you mouse functions on the svg will work?  Do you want to use it to toggle the line drawing ability off/on?  **OR** do you mean that clicking that button should draw a line?

Comment: I will have for example 3 buttons, Line, Circle, Rectangular. When I click Line button, I want to be able to draw a line with my mouse. When I click Circle, I want to be able to draw a circle with my mouse and also for rectangular.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue when using techanjs/d3 with vue.js -- does anyone know how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567677/d3-js-cannot-read-property-sourceevent-of-null#comment43562533_27567677), the problem is the way you deal with the buttons:

```
document.getElementById("lineBtn").onclick = function drawLine(){ 
    mousedown(); 
    mousemove(); 
    mouseup(); 
};
```

You cannot call these functions like this for several reasons, but mainly because there is no `this` being passed to `d3.mouse` and, therefore, no source event.

A better approach is using the buttons to set the correct listeners, like this:

```
d3.select("#lineBtn").on("click", function() {
  container.on('mousedown', mousedownLine)
    .on('mouseup', mouseupLine);
});

d3.select("#circleBtn").on("click", function() {
  container.on('mousedown', mousedownCircle)
    .on('mouseup', mouseupCircle);
});
```

Here is a demo (using D3 v5, which is not different from your v3 regarding this issue):

```js
var line;
var circle;
var container = d3.select("body").append("svg");

d3.select("#lineBtn").on("click", function() {
  container.on('mousedown', mousedownLine)
    .on('mouseup', mouseupLine);
});

d3.select("#circleBtn").on("click", function() {
  container.on('mousedown', mousedownCircle)
    .on('mouseup', mouseupCircle);
});

function mousedownLine() {
  container.on("mousemove", mousemoveLine);
  var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
  line = container.append("line")
    .attr("x1", coordinates[0])
    .attr("y1", coordinates[1])
    .attr("x2", coordinates[0])
    .attr("y2", coordinates[1]);
};

function mousemoveLine() {
  var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
  line.attr("x2", coordinates[0])
    .attr("y2", coordinates[1]);
};

function mouseupLine() {
  container.on("mousemove", null);
};

function mousedownCircle() {
  container.on("mousemove", mousemoveCircle);
  var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
  circle = container.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", coordinates[0])
    .attr("cy", coordinates[1]);
};

function mousemoveCircle() {
  var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
  circle.attr("r", Math.hypot(coordinates[0] - circle.attr("cx"), coordinates[1] - circle.attr("cy")));
};

function mouseupCircle() {
  container.on("mousemove", null);
};
```

```css
line {
  stroke: teal;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

circle {
  stroke: tomato;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button id="lineBtn">Line</button>
<button id="circleBtn">Circle</button>
```